# How to change Tax computation from lines to order?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Right now in standard Odoo accounting, it calculates taxes by line, and then sum the tax at the end of the invoice/bill.

However, what I need is to rewrite it so that it no longer calculates taxes in the lines, but rather calculate the taxes at the end of the invoice/billing.

I already forced the lines to have the same taxes so it can calculate correctly because every line is guaranteed to have the same taxes now.

The question is where and how should I rewrite the `account.move` module for this requirement?

I already did this implementation successfully in Sale. However, there are many complex methods in the `account.move` that are very different from what I did in `sale.order`. So, I am at lost here.

Right now, I am messing (trying) with `_recompute_tax_lines` but I am sure there are other methods needed to be overrided, which I do not know all of them.

[image: tax calculation]

Comment: What about the settings found in Accounting \ Configuration \ Settings \ Rounding Method changing to "Round Globally"? Or did i misunderstand your requirement?

Comment: @CZoellner This question has nothing to do with rounding. I just want to move the calculation of taxes from Line to the end of the invoice/billing. The reason is that I have Global Discount, and I want the total price to deduct by line discount and then deduct by global discount. Only then, the tax must be calculated.

Comment: @CZoellner I added an image depicting my expected tax calculation.

Comment: Yes okay, that's not possible with existing settings.